# mysql replication What's best for my situation?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, webserver, replication

I currently have a website that keeps a lot of data about user game profiles. 
I would like to achieve: 
A quick way of ***scanning a non indexed varchar field for text using LIKE. currently over 17,000,000 rows in this one table. Ideally a way of doing it off the live database.***

This takes 30 seconds and locks the site, I don't do it often however there are nude avatars that I need to remove and sometimes contain the same path for multiple people so i can disable loads of people in one go, I avoid this where i can. Indexing the field doesn't have a major affect. 
The SQL is on a shared server running a vps with 6 cores , 2gb dedicated ram and a 100gb mechanical disk. SSD speeds didn't have a great impact on this specific search. 
So I thought about having replication again: (7mb/s down and 350kb/s up home connection)

**option 1:**
Master to Master from VPS to my home machine. My home machine is a 3770k with 16gb ram and a SSD , I would be confident this would return quick searches and remains online a lot of the time. I could run the processing side of things on this machine to then relay back to the web side.

**Option 2:** 
Master to slave. Using the slave on my local machine to generate the fields that need modifying and I can write code to fire this back to the main server to update it there although a bit of a ball ache.

**option3**: Get the spare quad core setup on my network and use that as a 24/7 dedicated slave here. Q6600 @ 3.5ghz with 4gb ram and mechanical disks. Although power usage is high and its fooking loud, the Mrs wouldn't be too happy!

**option4:** Get another vps although I want to keep costs down.

Could anyone shed some light on what's best? I don't have a great deal of experience with this kind off thing. Although I've setup data replication in the past im sure people reading this would have more knowledge on performance impacts and do's and don'ts.

Comment: Why can't you index this column?

Comment: @WayneWhitty If he's looking for a string in the middle of the URL, an index won't help. It can only speed up exact or prefix matching.

Comment: Indexing has no effect. Ideally I want to bring some strain off the main SQL server. These searches im doing are needed although not the best thing to do really because it balls the server, The site is busy and I would like to run some other sql stuff which is mainly for administration off site. Its not busy enough for load balancing, infarct everything for the user front end is quick its just stuff in the back end i would like to do, stat generation, and general full table scans.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, I did not know that. Sounds like LIKE isn't the best approach.

Comment: @MartinSheen Why can't you check the image on output and deal with it there and then? Create some sort of filter that black lists certain images? i.e. Stop them from being displayed and/or delete them just before the image is expected to be outputted?

Comment: I dont know the image is bad until I see it / its reported. I have automation which scores images on a nudity level and is set for reviewing. Anywhere between 10,000 and 50,000 records are added daily (all automated) so its hard to keep up. Some avatars have the same image path.
/ee/ee5c3f8f2c52af11886806a03fceeaa31b9a33b2_full.jpg and this is unique a lot of the time however I believe steam detects images that have already been uploaded and points other profiles to the previous uploaded image meaning i can wipe out sometimes hundreds of nude images in one "set nude = 1 where icon like %bla%"